# Regex match pattern after positive look ahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex that is doing a positive lookahead. The positive lookahead relies on "cfu/ml" being present in the string but doesn not include it in the result.

Here's the regex:

```
((((less|greater)\s*tha[nt]\s*)?[><]*[\d]+[\sx,.-]*)*)+(?=CFU\s?/\s?ML)
```

Ex string: "100,000,000 x 85 x 9345 cfu/ml"

Match1: "100,000,000 x 85 x 9345"

That's working just fine, but trying to match anything after that positive lookahead is not working. What I'm trying to do is add another result capture group after the positive look ahead like so.

```
((((less|greater)\s*tha[nt]\s*)?[><]*[\d]+[\sx,.-]*)*)+(?=CFU\s?/\s?ML)\s*blah
```

Ex string: "100,000,000 x 85 x 9345 cfu/ml blah"

Match1: "100,000,000 x 85 x 9345"

Match2: "blah"

Seems like nothing after the positive look ahead works, anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookaheads are *zero-width* -- they don't match any characters, they just assert that certain conditions are true at that point in the string.  So if the lookahead matches, then the characters after it will be `CFU / ML` or whatever else your lookahead would match.

You want to *ignore* those characters, though -- which means not just asserting they exist, but actually consuming them so they don't become part of a match group.  For example, you might make your lookahead be a non-capturing group instead.  The full matched string will still have those extra chars in it, but the capture groups won't include them.

Comment: To put it another way, positive lookaheads are kind of pointless to put in the middle of a regex. Practically speaking, you really would only want to use them at the end of a regex. Ditch the lookahead and just use a normal expression.

Comment: ok I see what you guys are saying, something like this  (((less|greater)\s*tha[nt]\s*)?[><]*[\d]+[\sx,.-]*)*CFU\s?/\s?ML\s*(blah)

Comment: @mgmedick: Basically, yeah.  I think.  Markdown mangled your comment a bit, but the grouping looks about right.

Comment: @mgmedick: If you don't want the subpatterns to be part of the match group, though, you might want to make them non-capturing as well.  `(?:subpattern)` is good for that.  And your pattern looks like it'll match strings like `100,000,000 x >85 x less than 9345 CFU/ML blah`.  It's up to you whether that's valid, or if it isn't, whether you have to worry about ever getting such a string.