# How to prove capturing groups inside look aheads should or should not be allowed by Sublime Text syntax parser?

Tags: regex, syntax, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, pcre

On the issue:

1. [SublimeTextCore$1796](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1796) Accept capture groups defined inside a look ahead

Currently all capturing groups inside look aheads are thread like non-capturing groups by Sublime Text syntax files. Therefore I am trying to prove that capturing groups inside look ahead are valid regular expression, i.e., allowed and should not be ignored by the Sublime Text syntax regex parser.

My arguments are that they are perfectly valid because there is not reason to ignore them. In contrast, the online regex engine on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UlNaHg/2) for PCRE v2 for PHP is implementing the capturing groups inside the look aheads, as we may see on the example bellow:

[image]

1. https://regex101.com/r/UlNaHg/2

Hence:

1. Is it a bug on Sublime Text to treat capturing groups inside look ahead as non-capturing groups?
2. Or is it a bug on the regex engine PCRE v2 for PHP to not tread capture groups inside look ahead as non-capturing groups?

Therefore is it wrong to treat capture groups inside look ahead as non-capturing groups? Can this be answered based in facts, i.e., a concrete proof to determine whether it correct or not? For example:

> By the definition of capturing groups in regular expressions, they must be ...

Their arguments again capturing groups being invalid inside look ahead are:

> Lookaheads are zero-width -- they don't match any characters, they just assert that certain conditions are true at that point in the string.
>
> [Regex match pattern after positive look ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935128/regex-match-pattern-after-positive-look-ahead)

Moreover, is it correct to not accept the capture groups inside the look ahead? i.e., treat then as non-capturing groups because they are zero-width, i.e., not match any characters?

---

## Update

To test whether Sublime Text is accepting capture groups inside a look ahead on this syntax file, we can create the following steps:

1. Create a syntax file named `test.sublime-syntax` on the `User` folder:

   ```
   %YAML 1.2
   ---
   name: test
   scope: source.syntax_name

   contexts:
     main:
       - match: '(look)(?=(ing))'
         captures:
           1: first.looking.assignment
           2: second.looking.assignment
         push:
           - meta_scope: third.looking.assignment
           - match: ''
             pop: true
   ```
2. Create a new file and set its syntax to `User/test`, and add the contents

   ```
   looking
   ```
3. Check the scopes names for the `look` and `ing`.

This is demonstration for the current behavior:

[image]

Here we may notice Sublime Text is completely ignoring the capture group inside the look ahead.

Comment: All regex engines allow capture groups inside assertions. It's probably how you're using it. A simple test is `(?=(...))` then print out group 1. What you have to remember is that inside assertions is like an independent sub-expression, i.e. it's like an expression without the assertion construct. Each assertion is passed it's own private reference point and matches from that position. It advances it's private position as needed. When done, it returns true/false whereby the caller continues from the callers current position.

Comment: In other words, each assertion has a private copy of the current position which it advances as needed, can capture, can call other assertions, and do anything as would a separate regex could do. It just doesn't advance the outter/main current position and it returns a true/false condition. You might just think of it as a function call with private position. Capture groups and references are otherwise exactly the same.

Comment: No need to try to print the group, use this: `...(?=(...))\1` If the string is greater than 7 and it matches, it supports  captures inside assertions. An other way is to read the doc's.

Comment: Thanks, I used `\2` on the example, instead of repeating it: https://regex101.com/r/UlNaHg/3, so they just do support capture groups inside look ahead expressions. I am going to try to abort the issue for this point of view.

Comment: After some testing I figured out Sublime Text is accepting capture groups inside look ahead/behind, Sublime text is just not applying any scope to the text if the text is not eaten by the regular expression. https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1796#issuecomment-312957520